# Issue with white space

Tags: html, css

I have no idea why there is this white space between Contact and the data under it. I tried 0px margin everywhere but the white space is still there. 
Any idea how to solve?

CSS: http://pasted.co/7d58de85

Thanks

[a screenshot of the part I am reffering to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQBO1.png)

```
    <header>
        <section id="logo">
            <img src="logo2.png" id="logoimg" alt="logo">
        </section>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="#top"><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href="#Agenda"><li>About Me</li></a>
                <a href="#HetTheater"><li>Projects</li></a>
                <a href="#edge2"><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <footer>
        <p id="contactgegevens">
           xxxxxx xxxxxxx 
           xxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com
           tel: xx xxxxxxxx
         </p>
        </footer>

    </header>
```

Comment: What is "Contact"? The `nav` or the `#contactgegevens`?

Comment: I have created fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Ramkee/6bme8za2/, can you please explain your issue.

Comment: its a list item inside nav

Comment: #contactgegevens is the data under it, so the white space is between the list item Contact and the data #contactgegevens

Comment: You can't do `<ul><a><li>`, the only *valid* (direct) element inside a `<ul>` is `<li>`. Inside a list item, you can add a link.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I will adjust it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining a `height` (`60vh`) to your `nav` and that's causing the issue.

Removing it, causes the height to be auto, and the white space disappears

```
nav{
    margin:0px;
    width:230px;
    min-width:150px;
}
```

Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NrWdzE).

The defined `height` was also causing some responsive issues.

Comment: Thankyou for the solution, it's fixed.

Comment: Nice. If my solution helped you, please upvote it and accept as the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Harry, I'll keep that in mind. I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have fix height on header and header has border.

```
header{
  height: auto;
    width:230px;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/znr1n39s/